# Syntactical use of WITH in SQL for CTEs and Properties

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, amazon-athena, presto, with-statement

I know two uses of `WITH` in SQL:

1. To signify a CTE (Common Table Expression) clause, creating a temporary table for use in the present query, and
2. To dictate properties in a CTAS (CREATE TABLE AS) statement, e.g. [Presto](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/create-table-as.html), [AWS Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table-as.html), [Cloudera](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/impala_create_table.html), etc.

However, in reading long queries, I have on several occasions had diffculty immediately telling these two uses apart, and I always thought to myself if it would have made more sense to use another word for one of the two, to improve readability and avoid ambiguity.

So my question is: are these two uses related somehow? Do they stem from some common root?

Comment: FYI: a third one is in [table hints in T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not related at all.  `WITH` is a syntactic construct similar to a subquery.  The other is used for other purposes.

An analogy by might the `BY` in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.  Or the `AND` used for `BETWEEN` and as a stand-alone boolean operator.  They just happen to have the same name.